# How to do Image loading animation?

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I am using Flash Build Image control to load the image from outside using .source attribute, I want to add the percentage animation for the loading process of each image, just wondering how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) are showing that Image is SWFLoader, and SWFLoader has `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
private var loader:Loader;
private var request:URLRequest;

function loadImage() {

 loader=new Loader();
 request=new URLRequest(image_path);

 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);

 loader.load(request);
}

function loadProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {

 // The following variable holds the ratio of loaded bytes to total bytes
 // Use it to increase size, show percentage, etc

 var pct:Number = loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesLoaded/loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal;

}

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {

 // Add all events that are to be fired after loading of the image

}
```

Call the loadImage function start the loading of the image.